# Will switching from a Nikon D60 to a Canon EOS 60D be better for night photography, city photography, and portraits?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, canon, nikon, upgrade

I am currently using Nikon D60 and have been itching to upgrade for some time. There are a lot of things about Canon EOS 60D that seem very appealing to me. The higher resolution, the sensor that appears to be similar as the one in much higher-end 7D, video, 5.3 fps continuous shooting, light and small camera body. I have not researched what lenses are available and would be good start with, but very excited about the prospect.

What can i expect as far as going from Nikon D60 (with default 18-55mm lens) to this Canon? Is it a good step? Would it be better for night photography? What lens would be ideal for city photography and people?

I don't have any good lenses with the Nikon. just the default that came with the D60, which I am not particularly attached to.

Additionally, it appears that it would be considerably more expensive to upgrade going the Nikon route.

UPDATE

hmm, according to this comparison, the image quality is almost identical
http://snapsort.com/compare/Canon_EOS_60D-vs-Nikon_D60
i'd say that would be a factor not to upgrade to this model.

Comment: Do you not have Nikon lenses that you would want to carry over to a new camera? The Nikon D7000, for example, has very similar specs to the 60D.

Comment: I have the 60D and although I do like it I wish I paid a little extra to get the weather-sealed, feature-richer 7D. The only think i would miss is the flip out screen which i love and use all the time.

Comment: These to existing questions might answer most of what you are wondering about - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/what-should-someone-know-when-switching-from-canon-to-nikon http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3363/what-are-the-most-notably-differences-between-canon-and-nikon-lenses

Comment: dpollitt do you think its a good idea?

Comment: On your update: Snapsort is a very deceptive site for comparing what you're trying to compare. It's fine for side-by-side feature lists, but its representation of DxOMark sensor scores is horribly abusive. In this case, you've drawn the right conclusion (not a huge difference) but be aware that there's also not a huge difference in many things the site will claim to be dramatically better or worse. That said, the Sony sensor in the Nikon D7000 or Pentax K-5 _is_ a generation better (especially at high ISO) but this is exactly what I meant about tech leapfrogging — next model maybe Canon wins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't have an investment in the system, there's no compelling reason to stay with the same brand when upgrading. Since you've had your camera for a while, you should think about what you like about it and what you're missing. It sounds like there are a few things about the Canon model that really appeal to you, so that's good. I'd suggest making an even broader list of wishes (without having a model in mind) and then looking more widely at current offerings to see what fits your desires best.

If small and light is important to you, you may want to consider going away from DSLRs entirely, to something like a Micro Four Thirds camera from Olympus or Panasonic, or even Fujifilm's X100. Or, for high frame rate, Sony's SLT cameras are hard to beat. And, of course, take lens size into account as well: the Canon 60D isn't small or light with L glass attached; maybe something like the the comparable Pentax K-5 with a [few nice prime lenses](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/13594/1943) would fit you best.

You note that you haven't looked at lenses available. That's definitely a time to stop and step back. You've got some experience and idea of what works and what doesn't, so now you're *probably* going to be wanting to buy into a system that you'll stick with for a while. You should definitely take a look at [How much do lens lineups vary across DSLR platforms?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9355/how-much-do-lens-lineups-vary-across-platforms), and maybe [this for flash](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16643/what-are-the-differences-between-e-ttl-i-ttl-and-p-ttl) as well.  Don't just consider the feature list of this year's latest model. They're always leapfrogging over each other, and if you make your decision that way, you'll always be unhappy a year later. Instead, consider the system as a whole — the camera system, and the general approach of the company, and how that fits with you as a photographer.

It's probably also a good time to think about ergonomics and other little things. The controls systems on Nikon and Canon are rather different. And in my subjective view, the camera companies with less market share put more thought into this — Pentax and Olympus particularly. And Sony tends to have be very photographer-oriented, and utilitarian — which makes sense when you know that their camera division comes from a buyout of Minolta. You can adapt, but if you're really comfortable with the way your current camera works — or find it annoying — that's something to take into account. A camera that's a joy to use is a camera you'll use more. (And that alone may make it worth investing a little more than you might otherwise — something I [strongly advocate](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5883/are-there-disadvantages-to-a-prosumer-camera-for-a-beginner-aside-from-cost) at the mid/entry level.)

Of course, upgrading your camera isn't a magical path to better pictures, but with digital technology upgrades are inevitable. You might, though, want to look at whether your money is better spent somewhere else: a new lens or other accessories for your current camera. (See [After 2 years of amateur photo, buy a new body or a great lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17952/after-2-years-of-amateur-photo-buy-a-new-body-or-a-great-lens))

Comment: wow. lot's of great advice thanks! i'll study all the links you've provided. this is more thinking that i initially hoped for, but probably best done now :). i will say that i love the way my nikon feels in hand, and where the controls are situated.. but i think i am just used to them and will adjust to a new camera.

Comment: Good answer! Definitely not a small and light body but rather a full size. With a battery grip and a 70-200 telephoto it gets heavy.

Comment: hey Matt, would you say that there would be a noticeable image quality difference going from nikon D60 to to the canon 60D ? or are they too similar..

Comment: @SonicSoul: from an absolute point of view, there are minor differences in technical image quality but they are basically the same. Online reviews focus on emphasizing small differences in measurements as very important, because that impression of being scientific and objective is what "sells" reviews. In a real sense, the difference to your photographs will be more impacted by different controls, the pentaprism viewfinder, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

For night photography, you do *not* want to use the kit lens. Get a 50mm F1.8 or 50mm F1.4, they are not expensive, and will do wonders for your night shots. It will make more impact, for fewer dollars that changing bodies -- whether it is within Nikon's line, or switching to Canon.

Comment: what about differences in sensor quality, and ISO range (as far as night photography) wouldn't switching to this model make a difference?

Comment: ISO range specs are marketing material, you have to take them with a grain of salt. The pro bodies have better low-light abilities than the enthusiast level cameras such as the 60D or D60. They also cost a bunch more.

For portraits, learn to use an inexpensive strobe. Read strobist.com. All cameras take photos with light. Learn to use light to your advantage.